# .alloc()' is unavailable in Swift: use object initializers instead

Tags: swift2

```
public func swiftObjWithDict(dict: NSDictionary, cos: AnyClass) -> AnyObject? {
    let obj: AnyObject = cls    // It’s cls() before, but in swift 2.0 it’s unavailable.
    let value = "xxx"
    let k = "created_at"
    obj.setValue(value, forKey: k)     // throw an error

}
```

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key created_at.'

What is the alternative to `alloc()` in Swift 2.0?

Comment: What is `cls` exactly?

Answer (score 1):

```
import Foundation

class A {
    func f() {
        print("A class")
    }
}
class B: A {
    override func f() {
        print("B class, child of ", terminator:"")
        super.f()
    }
}

func foo(cls: AnyClass)->AnyObject? {
    switch cls {
    case is B.Type:
        return B()
    case is A.Type:
        return A()
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

if let a = foo(A.self) as? A {
    a.f()
}

if let b = foo(B.self) as? B {
    b.f()
}
```

OK, this has nothing with compiler error. What is the parameter dict in your function for? It is dictionary (key value coding-compliant). Check your code again, or explain us, what you are trying to do ...